# Making a TableViewController a subview of a TableViewController (ios)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, class, ipad

I am trying to add pull to refresh to my app and am using the Pull to Refresh files here: https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh However I am confused on how to make a subclass of my table view. How does one do that?

Comment: what exactly are you confused about?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
@interface MyTableViewController : PullRefreshTableViewController
{
    //Member variables here.
} 

// Methods and protocols here.

@end
```